# How to convert a time string into UTC time string format in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, momentjs, dayjs

I have a 24 hour time looks like `14:00` and I want to convert this into today's utc time string format which is looks like `Mon Dec 19 2022 14:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`. How can I do this in javascript.

Comment: `Mon Dec 19 2022 14:00:00 GMT+0530` is not *"...today's utc time string format..."* UTC is not a format, it's a time zone (Universal Time, Coordinated). (You may be thinking of ISO, but that's not an ISO-8601 format either.)

Answer (score 2):

That isn't UTC, that's local time in India.

The output looks like the now-defined¹ output of the `Date` [`toString`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date.prototype.tostring) method, so you need to:

1. Create a `Date` instance for today with `14:00` as the time (local time).
2. Use `toString`

```js
// Your time string
const time = "14:00";
// Split it into hours and minutes as numbers
const [hours, minutes] = time.split(":").map(Number);
// Get a date for "now"
const dt = new Date();
// Set its hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds
dt.setHours(hours, minutes, 0, 0);
// Get the string
const str = dt.toString();

console.log(str);
```

For me here in England that outputs `Mon Dec 19 2022 14:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)`, but for someone in India it should output something in that time zone.

---

¹ For a very long time, the output of `toString` wasn't precisely defined. As of recent specifications, it is.

Comment: `.map(Number)` is unnecessary, the values are mapped to number anyway by [*setHours*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.sethours) using *ToNumber*. ;-)

Comment: @RobG - :-) Quite true. I prefer to keep my conversions explicit, but quite true.